# Passing the props from screen under stack navigator to the shared appbar using react native paper and react native navigation v5

Tags: reactjs, react-native, navigation, react-native-paper

Here's my environment:

```
"react": "17.0.1",
"react-native": "0.64.0"
"@react-navigation/native": "^5.9.4"
"@react-navigation/stack": "^5.14.4"
"react-navigation-stack": "^2.10.4",
"react-native-paper": "^4.7.2",
```

I'm successfully implemented the integration using [this guide](https://callstack.github.io/react-native-paper/integrate-app-bar-with-react-navigation.html). Here's my current inplementation for the stack navigator.

```
<AuthContext.Provider value={authContextValue}>
  <NavigationContainer>
     <Stack.Navigator
       screenOptions={{
         header: props => <Appbar {...props} />,
        }}>
      <Stack.Screen name="Verval" component={HomeScreen} />
      <Stack.Screen name="ClaimForm" component={ClaimFormScreen} />
     </Stack.Navigator>
  </NavigationContainer>
</AuthContext.Provider>
```

AppBar.js

```
import React, {useContext} from 'react';
import {Appbar} from 'react-native-paper';

import {AuthContext} from '../../utils/authContext';

import {months} from '../../utils/helpers';

export default function CustomNavigationBar({navigation, previous}) {
    const {logout} = useContext(AuthContext);

    const today = new Date();

    const _handleChangeMonth = () => console.log('Change month');
    const _handleSearch = () => console.log('Searching');
    const _handleLogout = () => logout();

    return (
      <Appbar.Header>
        {previous ? <Appbar.BackAction onPress={navigation.goBack} /> : null}
        {!previous ? (
          <>
          <Appbar.Content
            title="My App"
            subtitle={months[today.getMonth() + 1] + ' ' + today.getFullYear()}
          />
          <Appbar.Action
            icon="calendar-month"
            color="white"
            onPress={_handleChangeMonth}
          />
          <Appbar.Action icon="magnify" color="white" onPress={_handleSearch} />
          <Appbar.Action icon="import" color="white" onPress={_handleLogout} />
          </>
       ) : (
          <Appbar.Content
             title="Claim Form Title"
             subtitle="Claim Form Subtitle"
          />
       )}
      </Appbar.Header>
     );
  }
```

For the logout function it can be passed using auth context provider. How can I passed the props/function beetween my HomeScreen and my AppBar for the handleChangeMonth and and handleSearch function because it needed by the HomeScreen to refetch the data?

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this,
<Stack.Screen initialParams={{userAuth: true}} />